# Change the font size within a pasted shape in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Does anyone know how to change the font size within a pasted shape object in PowerPoint?

I was able to successfully manipulate the shape with the following:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

However, when I try to change the font size with the following, I get an error:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
```

I am pasting a pivot table from Excel...I tried following but got an error:

```
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim l As Long
Dim j As Long

Set oShp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
Set oTbl = oShp.Table

For l = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
For j = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count

oTbl.Cell(l, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16

Next
Next
```

The error was Method Table of object Shape failed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change index (j,l)

```
oTbl.Cell(j, l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16
```

Comment: Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The specified value is out of range. I am pasting a pivot table from Excel - Could it be that I need to try and manipulate the Table Object?

Comment: Check for the slide index or shape index.

Comment: No issue with incorrect slide index or shape index.

Comment: Change index (j,l)

Comment: Make sure you paste the pivot table to table format and not picture or incorporate

Comment: Do you know the paste format to make sure it's pasted in table format? Thanks!

Comment: table format : you can edit the table; I created an example with the same code you used it Works.

Comment: You were right all along. It was my Shape(index) that was wrong! Thanks!

Comment: Why does it work sooo slowly? Any chance to speed this up?