# Changing font size within a Shape object (Table) in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

I'm trying to change a font size for the Shape object I'm pasting to PowerPoint from Excel. This is a table that looks like this:

[image: Shape Object - Table]

I used the way presented in this thread, and it works but the problem is that it works extremely slow:

[Change the font size within a pasted shape in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481106/change-the-font-size-within-a-pasted-shape-in-powerpoint)

Any idea how to speed this up? Is there a method that could replicate a behavior of Ctrl + A within a shape and change the font instantly instead of going through each and every cell within a table?

Comment: I can't find anything that works, though ... and this may point to some sort of solution ... if you select a table (ie, click within it then press ESC to select the table shape, not one of its cells) then choose a font, the new font applies to all the text within the table.

Comment: Would be easier if they didn't remove recording macro feature within PowerPoint... I find this quite useful to look up for certain objects/methods etc.

Comment: Assuming the macro recorder would record anything that you did with tables, yes. But it never did that, so if they brought it back, it'd still be useless in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up an array of cells seemed to improve the speed of the macro you are referring to. I tested it with a table with 120 rows and 3 columns and it took one second against the 11 of the one you linked. however, the more I test it, the more various the runtime.

I made two versions, in the first the font size is applied at the end, in the second during the building of the arrays. It took the same amount of time, so it's up to you which one you prefer. I changed the slide index for all three for testing purposes, so you may have to edit that.

Just for reference, I am also posting the code you mentioned.

**Original code**

```
Sub changefontsizetablesoriginal()


Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim l As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim tT As Long

tT = Timer

Set oShp = ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(1)
Set oTbl = oShp.Table


For i = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
oTbl.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12

Next j
Next i
Debug.Print Format(tT, "mm.ss.ssss")
End Sub
```

**Edited code (supposedly faster, based on array of cells)**

```
Sub changeFontSizeInTable()

Dim oSld As PowerPoint.slide
Dim oShp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oTbl As PowerPoint.Table
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim cellArr() As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim tT As Long

tT = Timer

Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set oShp = oSld.Shapes(1)
Set oTbl = oShp.Table


ReDim cellArr(oTbl.Rows.Count, oTbl.Columns.Count)
For i = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count


Set cellArr(i, j) = oTbl.Cell(i, j).Shape


Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count

cellArr(i, j).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16


Next j
Next i


Debug.Print Format(tT, "mm.ss.ssss")

End Sub
```

```
Sub changeFontSizeInTable2()

Dim oSld As PowerPoint.slide
Dim oShp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oTbl As PowerPoint.Table
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim cellArr() As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim tT As Long

tT = Timer

Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
Set oShp = oSld.Shapes(1)
Set oTbl = oShp.Table

ReDim cellArr(oTbl.Rows.Count, oTbl.Columns.Count)
For i = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count

Set cellArr(i, j) = oTbl.Cell(i, j).Shape
cellArr(i, j).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12

Next j
Next i

Debug.Print Format(tT, "mm.ss.ssss")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll test it out as soon as I get back to the project.